# Source Analysis tools for Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I'm after a source analysis tool that will run on mono ( think stylecopcmd ), stylecop has a number of holes that stop it working for me without gross hacking ( eg hard-coded to use "\" as a directory separator )

I am happy using gendarme to analyse assemblies but would like to check the source as-well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this on and off for a while now, I decided to modify StyleCopCmd to run on Linux under mono.
http://github.com/inorton/StyleCopCmd

The only changes I have made so far have been to use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of `\`;

Comment: Try make a contribution or write a change request

Comment: I've contributed my patch to the stylecopcmd folks but have as yet had no reply. My github 'fork' is stable and works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) on any .NET assemblies, mono or vs.

For static analysis there is [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), which is a commercial product.

Comment: Reflector isn't a source analysis tool. It only handles compiled assemblies.

Comment: @IanNorton - True, but you did ask about checking the source as-well.